# How to install freeglut with python 3.6

Tags: python, freeglut

I tried to install freeglut on Python 3.6 version, but it doesn't work.

I entered the freeglut.dll path in Path, I ran `py -3.6 -m pip install pyopengl`, I also put dll in system 64. What should I do? Can you help me?

```
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutInit, check for bool(glutInit) before calling
```

Comment: Could you explain your operating system?

Comment: py  -m pip install pyopengl --upgrade